# Bathroom leak / door trim rotten

Tags: bathroom

Hope someone can help me with this; as you can see in the pic, one of my door trim situated near my shower was starting to rot at the bottom
Removed the panel and now left with this...
Was thinking of redoing the silicone Inside the shower screen and putting some silcone between the tile and the wall. You can see the membrane under the tile, which stops at the trim, should I continu this membrane before putting trim in place ? 
You can see in above pic that the silcone is not done Under the shower screen.
Hopefully someone can advise the best way to fix without having to redo the tile and membrane.

Cheers
[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The tiles should be ok, except for mold (which is easy to clean). 100% I'd apply silicone under the shower screen (external and internal if possible). Replace the door trim if possible (depending of your budget) if not and if you have a multitool remove the lower part and try your best covering it. Before anything, clean everything and apply an anti mold solution, since probably you already have some dots (based on the extent of the pictures)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to extend the waterproof membrane. Your problem could be as simple as re-caulking the shower door/enclosure, but it could also be more complex and difficult, depending on the source area of the leak.

You did not include any photos of the tile corners and shower floor. Water could easily be traveling to the affected area from somewhere other than the shower door. Even if the tiled areas *appear* sound, tiled surfaces are porous (hence the need for waterproofed substrate) and your waterproof membrane could be compromised somewhere.

Leave that trim area uncovered and let it dry out. Start with the easiest fix, thoroughly and properly caulk the shower door/enclosure unit. Watch for any further signs of moisture/leaks. If the problem persists then you need to try to find the source of the leak, which could include tearing up the tile floor and walls to find and fix (sorry).